# Oracle PL/SQL : Return 1 row from an outer join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have the following two tables -

### Table1

Name   Age   City

A              21    Delhi

B              23    Mumbai

C              35    Pune

### Table2

Name    Attribute    Attribute_value

A            Phone       999999999

A            Passport       A12345

A            Location       China

A            Skills        Developer

B            Phone       8888888888

B            Skills       Tester

Now I want to create table 3 where I get the following details -

### Table3

Name Age City Phone Passport Location Skills

Note- the attribute_values should come under the Phone, passport, Location and Skills headings.
There should be a single row per 'Name' in table 3.

[Assuming that there are only 4 distinct values in the attribute column in Table2 and for the Name where a certain attribute can not be found, the attribute_value can be assumed as NULL]

Comment: Can you share with us any SQL you have already written?

Comment: Besides, mention your expected output.

Comment: So basically want to join and pivot.  The solution from Utsav should work.

Comment: I used simple left join.. and got 4 rows corresponding to 1 name.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only `4` attributes, then you can use something like below.

Note: I am assuming that this is a test scenario you are working on. In actual database, `name` is not a good idea for a key, so you cannot base your processing based on `name`

```
select t1.*, t2.*
from
    table1 t1 
left join 
    ( select name,
    max(case when attribute = 'Phone' 
        then attribute_value end) as Phone ,
    max(case when attribute = 'Passport' 
        then attribute_value end) as Passport, 
    max(case when attribute = 'Location' 
        then attribute_value end) as Location,
    max(case when attribute = 'Skills' 
        then attribute_value end) as Skills
     from table2
     group by name
     ) t2 
on t1.name=t2.name
```

Left join is just to return `null` for `name` which are not in `table2`. If you dont want these, then use `inner join`.

Comment: yes, the key is not name. It is an id but the table structure is complex to explain here.